# jdbc connectivity with MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2007

i am trying to establish a connection with access database using java... 
But while trying to configure the database it showing the error as architecture mismatch between driver and the application..

[image]

[image]

[image]

My OS is 64 bit and office is 32 bit.... I resovled the same problem in oracle by placing the jar files **C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar** and  **C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar** in class path. But How can i solve this problem with access....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc][1] try to use ucanaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit ODBC Administrator utility (%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) supplied by Microsoft for its 64-bit OS does not solve the archirecture incompatibility since DSNs defined through it are usable only by apps also running in 32-bit mode.

Fortunately, Microsoft realized the issue and provided a component called “Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable”. You can download it from [Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255). After executing AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe you will be able to see the MS-Access driver under the normal 64-bit ODBC Administrator.